# Jquery to javascript conversion help

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert the following jquery to javascript syntax, but being not familiar with either, I'm getting stuck

```
var div = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;"></div>');
// Append our div, do our calculation and then remove it
$('body').append(div);
var w1 = $('div', div).innerWidth();
div.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
var w2 = $('div', div).innerWidth();
$(div).remove();
```

Comment: If you're not a javascript developer, wouldn't it make sense to use jQuery since it minimizes the amount of JS you actually have to write/comprehend?

Comment: Do you need support for all browsers?

Comment: Put a bounty on it and I'm sure someone will do the work for you.

Comment: @Rex, possible, but don't want to add the size of the jquery lib since I rarely ever need to use javascript. It's a one off thing that I'm experimenting with

Comment: @clamix - I can abbreviate the story and save you some grief here, by the time you convert more than 1 thing like this from jQuery to avoid using it, you'll wish you hadn't.  Then, you'll load it in IE and want  buy a bullet and rent a gun.  I'd use jQuery.  It's 24kb sent to the client then cached...that's less than a lot of webpages are each time, size shouldn't be a major concern unless it's a mobile application.

Comment: ok guys, thanks for the help. I know it's not too difficult for some of you, a combination of get element by id and create element. I'll look up the syntax one by one and try to convert it since there seems to be something wrong with my asking.

Comment: @clamix - It's getElementsByName, but inside a context, some of the jQuery width calculations that take into account margins, padding, etc...it's not that simple and very tedious to repeat, this is why we use jQuery :)

Comment: Theres a lot of work going on in the background, its not a line for line translation. Most javascript programmers use jQuery or Prototype because they remember the pain involved when you do it the old way. You dont have to go through this. Your time would be better spent learning jQuery.

Comment: "I'll look up the syntax...since there seems to be something wrong with my asking." There's nothing wrong with your asking, and the question is perfectly valid, it's just that you're making a whole lot of work for yourself that's unlikely to be as stable as the result achieved via jQuery (or any other JS library). Learn basic JS by all means, but for something that needs to be cross-browser and cross-platform stable/consistent, using a library to cover -at least- *most* of the edge cases that you won't be able to anticipate makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly translate jQuery into native JavaScript because it's pulling different tricks for all sorts of variables you couldn't possibly account for (browsers, browser versions, OSes, etc).

You could attempt to do this but it'd be an incredible waste of your time. The top JavaScript pros are working on these frameworks to make JavaScript easier for you. Don't undo all their hard work by trying to do it on your own...

Answer (score 1):

```
function scrollbarWidth2() {
    var outterDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    outterDiv.style.cssText = "width:50px;height:50px;overflow:hidden; background:red; position:absolute;top:200px;left:200px;";
    innerDiv.style.cssText = "height:100px;";
    outterDiv.appendChild(innerDiv); 
    document.body.appendChild(outterDiv);
    var w1 = innerDiv.offsetWidth;
    outterDiv.style.overflowY = "scroll";
    var w2 = innerDiv.offsetWidth;
    document.body.removeChild(outterDiv);
    return (w1 - w2);
}
```